# tableview cell.imageview is not animating

Tags: ios, uitableview, imageview, tableview

I am trying to animate `tableview` cell's `imageview` which is present by default, i want the image view to be animated only once when the cell is visible, for this i have written the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave6.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave7.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave8.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave9.png"]],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave10.png"]],nil];

        NSArray *titles = @[@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",
                            @"Test User",@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",@"John Appleseed", @"John Doe", @"Test User",
                            @"Test User"];
    [cell.imageView setAnimationImages:myImageArray];
    cell.imageView.animationDuration = 4.20;
    cell.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [cell.imageView startAnimating];


            cell.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it not related to your problem but for best practice- `cellForRowAtIndexPth` is not the place where you should create or initialise any array better put your initialisation code in `viewDidLoad` or elsewhere.

Comment: I tried you solution It is working for me fine when i do the scroll for next rows. Have you check you have given the proper name of images?? images are present in the resources or not??

Comment: first allocate myimagearray with your cell image view

Answer (score 4):

**1. Remove the animation code in cellforatindexpath**

**2. animate it when cell is displaying**

**3. stop animation while hiding the cells**

**4. Will Improve the performance of the App**

**5. Save more memory**

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSArray *myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave6.png"]],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave7.png"]],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave8.png"]],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave9.png"]],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave10.png"]],nil];

        [cell.imageView setAnimationImages:myImageArray];
        cell.imageView.animationDuration = 4.20;
        cell.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        [cell.imageView startAnimating];

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


        [cell.imageView stopAnimating];

        [cell.layer removeAllAnimations];

    }
```

instead of

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wave6.png"]
```

you could specify just like @"wave6.png"

Comment: initially in visible cells image must be present, while scrolling up image must animate as if there was no image and slowly image has to appear can we achieve this?@vijay.

Answer (score 1):

Create object of UIImageView and add on cell contentView

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
imageView.animationImages = myImageArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 4.20;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wave5.png"]
    ; // you can put any image
[imageView startAnimating];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate method in custom cell class

like this

```
@interface CustomCell ()

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        isAnimating = NO;
        [self startAni];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startAni{
    if (!isAnimating){
         isAnimating = YES;
    }
    //Animation Code here
}

- (void)stopAni{
    if (isAnimating){
         isAnimating = NO;
    }
    //Animation Code here
}
```